# How to import contact lists for angular 4 and spring boot? Are there any free api''s?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I want to import contact lists such as Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail. I have found info on PHP but I am using angular 4 and spring boot. They only refer to other technologies.

Comment: No clue who upvoted this question, but this is very, very broad and also unclear what you exactly want. And you're also asking for off-site resources (API's).

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find any resources to import these contact lists to these technologies. I have searched extensively but I am new to spring boot and have limited experience with angular 4. Can you please suggest how to rephrase my question?

Comment: The issue is that (a) you're asking for API's, which are off-site resources. Such questions are **not allowed** on SO. (b) It's broad because you're keeping the scope too broad (multiple technologies, multiple providers). To fix that, **limit the scope** by choosing either technology, and either Gmail, Yahoo, ... . Also try to use the info you found in PHP, but within Spring boot/Angular. If you're stuck with replicating the same thing in Spring boot/Angular, then ask a specific question about what you're stuck with.

Answer (score 3):

Lets see how we gonna do this

1. Connect with our google account
2. ask for the “scopes” that we are going to need
3. ask google the contact of the user
4. do what (you have to do) with those emails

**1 — Import javascript libraries**

inside your index.html and at the en of the body tag

```
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

**2 — initiate you component**

create your component and initiate your import of the api. Outside of you component code :

```
declare var gapi: any;
```

then you got to load the api like this :

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        setTimeout(() => this.signIn(), 1000);
    }

signIn() {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
        this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
            cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin',
            scope: 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'
        });
        this.auth2.attachClickHandler(document.getElementById('googleres'), {}, this.onSignIn, this.onFailure);
    })
}
```

the reason of the setTimeOut is simply to avoid try to load gapi before the api is completely downloaded. 1 second seems enough.

Replace **YOUR_CLIENT_ID** with the one you create in google developper console / web oauth credential.

See here we now have our button linked to our google Auth2 object, this means that we gonna be logged in when we click on it.

**3— On sign in and fetch emails**

when user accept this is what we want to do :

```
onSignIn = (data: any) => {

    setTimeout(() => this.fetchmail(), 1000);
}
data is containing our token

fetchmail() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
        gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: 'API_KEY use your own',
            discoveryDocs: ['https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'],
            clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
            scope: 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'
        }).then(() => {
            return gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
                resourceName:'people/me',
                personFields: 'emailAddresses,names'
            });
        }).then(
            (res) => {
                //console.log("Res: " + JSON.stringify(res)); to debug
                this.userContacts.emit(this.transformToMailListModel(res.result));
            },
            error => console.log("ERROR " + JSON.stringify(error))
        );
    });
```

now you have the users mailing list with names. Simple as that.

Reference:-[Angular 2 (or 4) Import google contacts](https://medium.com/@mcflyDev/angular-2-or-4-import-google-contacts-d0ffb13d8626)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try.